# Program to download all the videos I uploaded to Vimeo

Tags: video, download-manager, vimeo

I'm looking for a program that can:

- download all the videos I uploaded to Vimeo *at once* (i.e. I don't want to download videos one by one)

Bonus point if:

- is free
- works on Windows 7 (but can be browser extensions or web service)
- works without having to log into my Vimeo account (then only public videos will be downloaded)
- has a GUI

Answer (score 1):

JDownloader (Clean installs at https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=54725) has the ability to download Vimeo on batch, including all converted versions. If you wanted the originally uploaded version, that would come up to. It has a GUI and works through the standard APIs so doesn't need a login.

Comment: Thanks, can it download all the videos I uploaded to Vimeo *at once* (i.e. I don't want to download videos one by one) ?

Comment: It's a batch runner, so if you were to open up a page with all your links on, and copy all of that to the clipboard, it would crawl the links and list everything. By default it would have an entry for each resolution of the video, but there are plugin settings you can set to only use a specific one. From there there's a start all button which will do the lot, and put them into folders based on the filename.  From your perspective, it would be only one operation, but I think it queues them up 5 at a time by default to download.